# What is a Magento?

Tags: magento2

I don't know what a Magento is. Can someone please like tell me? I need help.

Answer (score 2):

Magento is an gift to the developers who wants to build an complete e-commerce without taking much efforts in-order to build architecture from scratch. It has been written in PHP. Magento is open source, so that anyone from anywhere can use it for free and are open to do any customization they want. Magento has broadly two types Magento 1 which was started in 2007 & now has reached near to its end of life.

Magento 2 is a new fresh makeover of Magento 1 release in 2015 with lot of changes in its architecture to make it better, secure & more loosely coupled and flexible. Couple of necessary features have been introduced in Magento 2.

Magento has support of a very enthusiastic community, who always try to help each others.
To know more about Magento simply download it from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and start using it.

For any query you can refer the official documentation anytime
https://devdocs.magento.com/ or put it on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ as you already did ;-)

Hope it was helpful to you.

Thanks